# Increment a Sequence vba

Tags: excel, vba

My sequence will be something like `0000-16x, 0001-16x, 0002-16x, … ,9999-16x`
I want to write a macro that will read one of the values and increment it by one. e.g. if it reads `0014-16x`the code will return `0015-16x`

My code works only if the contents of cell are all numbers

```
Dim name As Variant
name = ActiveCell
name = name + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = name
```

How can I increment a sequence like the one I have? Thanks

Comment: Assigning `FormulaR1C1` seems overkill in this case; you could be assigning the cell's `Value` directly. That said, with a UDF such as [Tim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245288/1188513) that becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and help. I am still new to vba function and all answers gave me something new to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no error checking:

```
Function NextSequence(v)
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(v, "-")
    NextSequence = Format(CLng(arr(0)) + 1, "0000") & "-" & arr(1)
End Function
```

Comment: I like how this solution avoids dealing with `ActiveCell`. Could be used as a UDF!

Comment: Nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the string by the delimiter of "-", increment the number by 1, append zeroes and reform our string - give this a shot:

```
Sub Increment()

    Dim name As Variant
    Dim firsthalf As String, secondhalf As String

    name = Split(ActiveCell, "-")(0)
    secondhalf = Split(ActiveCell, "-")(1)
    name = name + 1

    Select Case Len(name)
        Case 1
            firsthalf = "000" & name
        Case 2
            firsthalf = "00" & name
        Case 3
            firsthalf = "0" & name
        Case 4
            firsthalf = name
    End Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = firsthalf & "-" & secondhalf

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI: the case can be replaced with right("0000"&name,4)

Answer (score 1):

I can't currently test this since I'm posting from my phone, but you could use the `Split()` function with a `-` delimiter and add `1` to the `(0)` position of the array, join it back together and pad it with 0's until it's length is 8.

Example:

```
Dim name() As Variant
Dim jName as String
name = Split(ActiveCell,"-")
name(0) = name(0) + 1
jName = Join(name,"-")
Do Until Len(jName) = 8
    jName = "0" & jName
Loop
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = jName
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-VBA solution, FWIW...

`=TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)+1,"0000")&"-"&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,99)`

with `0000-16x` in cell A1 and the formula in cell A2. Simply fill down to extend.